# Returning data from BROWSABLE activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have an activity that's meant to be invoked from the Android browser via an Intent URI. Can I somehow return HTML to that browser from my activity?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can open an html document (probably from your assets directory) on an HTML-viewer. Hopefully this link will get you in the right direction:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/290f3349ff4bd03d#

Comment: This is not what I'm after. In the example, they open a browser from the activity with a given HTML. I want the browser to open my activity (that it already does) AND to have some HTML once it closes (or right away).